# Function that console.log's the total of all items together

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a function called `totalPriceCheck` that console.log's the total of all `shoppingCart` items together.

```
var shoppingCart = [];

function addToCart (name, price) {
    var object = {};
    object.name = name;
    object.price = price;
    shoppingCart.push(object);
}

function priceCheck(item){
    for (var i = 0; i < shoppingCart.length; i += 1) {
        if (item === shoppingCart[i].name) {
            console.log(shoppingCart[i].price + " sheqalim");
        } else {
            console.log("the searched item is not in the shopping cart array!");
        }
    }
}

function totalPriceCheck(){
    for (var i = 0; i < shoppingCart.length; i += 1) {
        var totalPriceOf = shoppingCart[i].price;    
        var myTotal = 0;  

        for(var i = 0, len = totalPriceOf.length; i < len; i++) {
            myTotal += totalPriceOf.price;  
        }
        console.log(myTotal);
    }
}

addToCart ('beer', 5);
totalPriceCheck();
```

Comment: What is the result of this code, did you get error or is it not printing anything?

Comment: the console logged a 0 .  5 is the current number

Comment: The total price of the cart IS 5, there's only beer in it. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: His code above logs 0 when it should log 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand your question properly but I think you need output like this.
I am doing some changes in your code, please refer below code

output of below code is :- **15**

if you add **addToCart('beer', 5);** than out put will be **20**

```
var shoppingCart = [];

function addToCart(name, price) {
    var object = {};
    object.name = name;
    object.price = price;

    shoppingCart.push(object);
}

addToCart('beer', 5);
addToCart('beer', 5);
addToCart('beer', 5);

function totalPriceCheck() {
    var myTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < shoppingCart.length; i += 1) {
        var totalPriceOf = shoppingCart[i].price;
        myTotal += totalPriceOf;
    }
    console.log(myTotal);
}

totalPriceCheck();
```

Comment: Nice.  I like it

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce to get the sum :

```
function totalPriceCheck(){
  return shoppingCart.reduce(
    (acc, elem)=>acc + elem.price, 
    0
  );
}
```

Comment: Good answer, here's a JS Fiddle using this @Andrew Zeitler https://jsfiddle.net/fgynovob/